# Maven command line to run TestNG which are packaged to jar

Tags: java, maven, testing, jar, testng

I have packaged my test project into a `.jar` file with pom and dependencies as `test-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`.  How can I use the Maven command line to run it?

I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
cd target
mvn test -DtestNG.file=testng.xml test-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

Run command

```
mvn test -DtestNG.file=/path/to/testng.xml
```

from root of your project or module (one level with pom.xml, src and target folders).

Test classes are not copied to the result jar and always run in the fixed phase (test phase).